# In Molpro, how to calculate the orbital angular momentum?

Tags: molpro, casscf, mrci, expectation-values

I wish to calculate the values of the orbital angular momentum of excited electronic states, using Molpro. So $\langle L_x \rangle$, $\langle L_y \rangle$, and $\langle L_z \rangle$. (Specifically for my case, I'm looking for the projection on the z-axis in a diatomic molecule. But I guess the answer should apply generally for all projections.) This should ideally be done at the `CASSCF` or `MRCI` level. But feel free to share procedures if they exist in other programs too.

I can find one mention of [these operators in the documentation](https://www.molpro.com/manual/doku.php?id=program_control&s%5B%5D=gexpec#one-electron_operators_and_expectation_values_gexpec), called `LOP` taken together, or `LX`, `LY`, `LZ`, individually. However they are listed with parity `-1`, and: "Expectation values are only nonzero for symmetric operators (`parity=1`)". Still, the electronic state must have some angular momentum. For instance, in `CASSCF` I can calculate the $\langle L_x^2 \rangle$, $\langle L_y^2 \rangle$, and $\langle L_z^2 \rangle$ with the card `EXPEC2,LXX,LYY,LZZ`. But then the sign of the projected angular momentum is lost, and I wish to compare signs for the different excited states.

Comment: Have you taken into account spin-orbit coupling (SOC)? The angular momentum expectation value of a real wavefunction is always 0, and as long as you don't take into account SOC and there isn't a magnetic field, the wavefunctions can always be taken as real. So you can only expect a non-zero expectation value of angular momentum if you turn on SOC

Comment: Did you try `LX` and confirm that you got zero?

Comment: Thanks @wzkchem5! I have indeed not turned on spin-orbit coupling. So this question is based on a misconception. I will leave it up for others who might be inclined to make the same mistake. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "However they are listed with parity `-1`, and: "Expectation values are
> only nonzero for symmetric operators (parity=1)"."

This matches the [comment by wzkchem5](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/6340/in-molpro-how-to-calculate-the-orbital-angular-momentum#comment12794_6340) which suggests that those expectation values, like $\left\langle \hat{L}_x \right\rangle$ which you correctly found to be listed as `-1` in the parity column of the table in the link you provided, will be zero. It may be true that $\left\langle \hat{L}^2_x \right\rangle$ is not zero, because there's no longer cancellation of positive and negative parts.

Comment: Thanks @Nike! This question was indeed based on a misconception (as you know, without spin-orbit coupling the wave-function is taken to be real, and $\langle L_x \rangle$ is zero). I will leave the question for others not to make my mistake. Cheers!